# python/ Django values_list is not returning all values

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I have this bit of ugly code that is producing what I want. It's working but only necessary because what I would like to do with `values_list` is not working.

```py
member_channels = Channel.objects.filter(Q(members=request.user) | Q(owner=request.user)).prefetch_related('members').prefetch_related('owner')

members_nested = list(map(lambda channel: channel.members.all(), member_channels))
members = list(dict.fromkeys(itertools.chain(*members_nested)))
owners = list(map(lambda channel: channel.owner, member_channels))

# this is all the user's who's comment's the request.user should be able to see.
valid_comment_users = list(dict.fromkeys(members + owners))
```

What I would like to do and should work is:

```py
member_channels = Channel.objects.filter(Q(members=request.user) | Q(owner=request.user)).prefetch_related('members').prefetch_related('owner')
member_ids = member_channels.values_list('members', 'owner', flat=True)
valid_comment_users = AppUser.objects.filter(id__in=member_ids).distinct()
```

The issue is that with `values_list` I'm not getting all the `members` for each Channel in the `members_channels` it seems like it's only returning the `members` that are the same in all channels, or maybe just the first member I can't tell. Any insight into why `values_list` isn't working for this?

Here are the models and their relationships:

```py
class Channel(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(AppUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(AppUser, blank=True, related_name="members")
```

```py
class Comment(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(AppUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    episode = models.ForeignKey(Episode, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

```py
class Episode(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(AppUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    channels = models.ManyToManyField(Channel, blank=True)
```

The `AppUser` is just the user model extended from Django auth.

Answer (score 1):

`flat=True` in `values_list` can only be used with one field:

so just remove flat=true and make a flat list out of it in python

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#values-list

Maybe something like this works better for you:

```
member_channels = Channel.objects.filter(Q(members=request.user) | Q(owner=request.user)).values_list("id", flat=True)
AppUser.objects.filter(Q(members__channel__in=members_channel) | Q(owner__channel__in=members_channel))
```

Going backwards, you just have to know the `related_query_name`. As you have 2 relations between `AppUser` and `Channel` I think you had to set this explicitly in either `related_query_name` or just `related_name`. So it is `.filter({related_query_name}__channel__in=...)`
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_query_name

Comment: got it, the issue still happens if I use `member_ids = member_channels.values_list('members', flat=True)` with only one field. Not all the members are returned in `member_ids`

Comment: Interesting, I'm not sure why it doesn't work. 
So you are saying that when you have some filtered channels, let's say `member_channels = Queryset [<Channel: 1>, <Channel: 2>]>` and then you do `member_channels.values_list('members', flat=True)` not all members are returned? That sounds weird, because that should actually work. Maybe you could post your models.py so that we can find the issue.
I just updated my answer with a different approach. Maybe that works better

Comment: yes! that's exactly the issue, not all the members are returned. Off your example I could take member_channels.first() and see there was one member and member_channels.last() and see there was two members. but after the values_list not all three members were returned. Nonetheless, I actually realized what I need is more complex and was able to get it working in a different way. But still strange values_list didn't work. I'll update the post with the models

Answer (score 0):

When `flat=True` is used, `values_list` returns a flat list of values instead of a list of tuples.

To retrieve both `members` and `owner` fields in a single `values_list` call, you should use it as:

```py
member_ids = member_channels.values_list('members__id', 'owner__id')
```

#### Edit

Try this:

```py
member_channels = Channel.objects.filter(Q(members=request.user) | Q(owner=request.user))
member_ids = member_channels.values_list('members__id', flat=True)
owner_ids = member_channels.values_list('owner__id', flat=True)
valid_comment_users = AppUser.objects.filter(Q(id__in=member_ids) | Q(id__in=owner_ids))
```

Comment: That makes sense, but the issue happens even If I only use `member_ids = member_channels.values_list('members', flat=True)` in which case not all the members are pulled into the `member_id` list.

Comment: @projectmind Maybe Some of the Channel objects in `member_channels` may not have any members. In this case, those objects will not contribute any data to the `values_list`, and the resulting list may be incomplete. See edited answer.

Comment: @projectmind Did you see the edited answer and the above comment?

Comment: yes, the issue is still there. I'm positive that there are 3 members that should be returned one from channel 1, two from channel two. Which I can check from member_channels directly. However values_list is only returning one member instead of all three. I found another way to solve what I ultimately needed but strange that values_list was acting that way.